# Установка программы

Tags: windows, delphi

Как в Delphi прописать, чтобы при запуске программа устанавливалась, как все остальные, типа setup.exe?

Answer (score 4):

Установщика как такового может и не быть. Нужно действительно быть уверенным в том, что нужен отдельный установщик, чтобы начать его делать. Обычно программа setup производит следующие действия:

- создание ключей в реестре для обеспечения работоспособности программы;
- создание конфигурационных файлов программы на основе выбора пользователя;
- копирование файлов программы в выбранную пользователем папку;
- создание ярлыков на рабочем столе и в меню "Пуск" для запуска программы;
- установка необходимых для программы компонентов и библиотек (напр., DirectX, .NET Framework и пр.)
- внесение необходимых изменений в системное окружение.

Возможны и другие шаги. Все эти действия можно сделать вручную в своей программе или заставить пользователя сделать их (дурной тон). Более того - бывает даже удобнее, если программа не требует ничего подобного, а запускается просто кликом по основному exeшнику и в систему "не гадит" - по крайней мере когда она станет не нужна, то не придется думать какой мусор за ней остался.

Т.к. в целом все действия, которые происходят в процессе установки больших программных продуктов, достаточно однотипные, то существуют специализированные инструментальные средства для написания инсталляторов. Как плюс - все инсталляторы выглядят практически одинаково и пользователь не удивляется, что необходимо в нем делать =)
Могу к уже перечисленным продуктам добавить:

1. [InstallShield](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) - вероятно самая мощная система, а заодно, по-видимому, одна из самых популярных среди крупных разработчиков коммерческого ПО. На рынке уже очень давно и является одной из самых первых программ такого рода.
2. [Wise Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions,_Inc.) - вторая по значимости среда для создания Installer'ов.
3. [NSIS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSIS) - бесплатная утилита. Создана разработчиками WinAMP'а. Весьма хорош, очень подходит для маленьких программ.
4. [Inno Setup](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) - еще один продукт, который следует отметить.

Еще один момент - как минимум первые два инсталлятора используют встроенную в Windows Microsoft Installer (MSI), которая и производит бОльшую часть необходимых для инсталляции программ действий. Т.к. правильно завязываться именно на нее, то большинство программ поставляются в виде msi, msp или cab-файлов, ну, и плюс свой setup.exe ;-)

Дополнительным способов установки программ можно назвать установку через информационные файлы *.inf. Обычно эти способом устанавливают драйвера и расширения для операционной системы, но возможно устанавливать и достаточно крупные программы, состоящие из множества файлов. Про то как писать эти инсталляционные файлы можно почитать на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547402.aspx)

Comment: Что то меня часто опережают) Inno setup очень простой. В смысле рекомендую его.

Answer (score 1):

В создании установщика сам код на Delphi участия не принимает. Нужно использовать подходящую утилиту. Например.

1. InstallAware (по-моему, идет в поставке вместе с Delphi).
2. WiX (бесплатный инструмент от Microsoft).
3. Advanced Installer (платный инструмент).

Answer (score 0):

Еще советую присмотреться к [Smart Install Maker](http://ru.sminstall.com/)

Answer (score 0):

В дистрибутиве Delphi 7 есть программа - InstallShield Express Borland
Прекрасно создающая Win-инсталляторы ПО.